# Why are my placed images all squatty in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

Just updated my Photoshop CC to 2017.

Now I'm trying to make an image by placing some equipment on a specific canvas size (440x240px).

[image: placing my image]

When I choose the image to place, it gets placed in Photoshop with skewed dimensions.

[image: my picture is squishy]

So, after struggling with this, I've just been manually adjusting each placed image. (Below is what this example should look like).

[image: how it's supposed to be]

And then, once I hit enter to actually place the image, the resolution drops. I have my file set up with 300 ppi specified and I've worked with placed imagery a lot. Usually it gains resolution after I place it.

[image: bad resolution]

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way?

Maybe I should just revert to the old version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution found!

Turns out Photoshop CC 2017 defaults every new item you create to have Pixel Aspect Ratio Correction on.

This function totally screws up what your looking at (which makes it essentially useless in my eyes, but maybe it's just buggy right now).

Before turning off pixel aspect correction ratio:

[image: wow that picture looks awful]

Here's where to find it if you need to turn yours off...

[image: Turning off that damn function]

And then, look at that! Your picture looks correct again. What do you know.

[image: Wow the image looks right!]